# Calculate the convolution of the product of two sine functions. (5.6-13)

Tags: laplace-transform, solution-verification, convolution

**Request**:

I cannot duplicate the answer in the book although I do get very close. This tells me that my method is correct but I am making another kind of error -- perhaps in my integration?

**Given**:

Find the convolution of $f(t)=sin(2t)$ and $g(t)=sin(t)$.

$$h(t)=(f*g)(t)=\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$$

**My Solution**:

Begin by inserting the functions into the formula and simplifying...

$$h(t)=sin(2t)*sin(t)=\int_0^t sin(2\tau)\cdot sin(t-\tau)d\tau=-\int_0^t sin(2\tau)\cdot sin(\tau-t)d\tau$$

We further simplify by applying the trigonometric product formula identity...

$$=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t[cos(\tau+t)-cos(3\tau-t)]d\tau$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2}\left[sin(\tau+t)-\frac{sin(3\tau-t)}{3}\right]_0^t$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2}\left[sin(2t)-\frac{sin(2t)}{3}-sin(t)+\frac{sin(-t)}{3}\right]$$

$$=-\frac{sin(2t)}{2}+\frac{sin(2t)}{6}+\frac{sin(t)}{2}+\frac{sin(t)}{6}$$

$$h(t)=-\frac{sin(2t)}{3}+\frac{2}{3}sin(t)$$

**Answer in Text**:

$$h(t)=-\frac{sin(2t)}{3}+\frac{2}{3}sin(t)$$

**Question**:

See bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as I was typing so nothing to do here. Thank you for checking my post regardless.

$$h(t)=-\frac{sin(2t)}{3}+\frac{2}{3}sin(t)$$